# WCF service using ASP.Net Forms authentification - error during $.ajax() call when cookie is expired

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS web site with forms authentification. The service has `[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]`
attribute and web config has this line:`<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />`

Service is called form page with $.ajax() call. Everithing works fine until when user calls service after his cookie has expired.
In this situation the window "Windows Security" appears, saing that user should put in login and password to access the service.
If the user just closes the windows without doing anything, the page is redirected to Login Page (that is right)

The question: how to skip this window and make redirection immidiately?
I guess there is something with configuring WCF service and I tried some schemes of binding - yet I can't escape this window.

The configuration of WCF service:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="metadataAndDebug">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Project.Service.DataServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="Project.Service.DataService" behaviorConfiguration="metadataAndDebug" >
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Project.Service.DataServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Project.Service.DataService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 0):

the feature autoredirect is on by default.

If for some reason, you want to turn this feature off, you can register a message inspector to do that.

```
public class MyMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    internal const string RedirectPropertyName = "WebHttpRedirect";
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        // remove the RedirectPropertyName from the request
        if ( request.Properties.ContainsKey(RedirectPropertyName))
        {
            request.Properties.Remove(RedirectPropertyName);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to turn of the redirection - I need it. I want to get rid of that "Windows Security" window that prompts for username and password.